# How to keep one icon name while clicking accordion item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a accordion dynamic with php wordpress. But by which source i found the accordion works correctly in html. but when i am trying to make it dynamic the font awesome icon don't work correctly. The font awesome icon repeats two time when it get expand. you can see below image

[image]

the code is here
https://jsfiddle.net/nriddhi/zyj3ck5t/

js code:

```
$(".accordion li h5").click(function () {
  var current_li = $(this).parent();
  $(".accordion li div").each(function(i,el) {          
    if($(el).parent().is(current_li)) {             
      $(el).prev().toggleClass("plus fa-minus");
      $(el).slideToggle();              
    } else{
      $(el).prev().removeClass("plus fa-minus");
      $(el).slideUp();
    }
  });
});
$('.accordion li > div').hide();
$('.accordion li h5').first().addClass("plus fa-minus");
$('.accordion li > div').first().show().addClass("plus");
```

how can i set font awesome icon class one time. and also when it will get expand there will only remain fa-minus icon and when will be closed there will be fa-plus icon. thanks for help....

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: The original HTML is: `class="icon fa-plus"`. Then you add `addClass("plus fa-minus")`. What result do you expect from that?

Comment: when i make it dynamic, expanding time font awesome icon not work correctly, sometimes it comes first fa-plus, sometimes fa-minus, how to keep one icon name and correct one, is there any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, you have the `fa-plus` class already applied to each accordion item trigger. Then, in your javascript, you're re-applying the `plus fa-plus` classes to each trigger, creating the class duplication.

Simply removing the additional js below your event handler takes care of the duplication, and explicitly stating an addition/removal of `plus fa-minus` or `fa-plus` to each clicked item will handle the change modifications.

Now, if you want to make each declaration of the accordion item trigger icons 100% dynamic, you'd have to provide some additional code to showcase how you're generating said elements, but within the context of the information that you've provided, this is the appropriate fix.

```js
$(".accordion li h5").click(function () {
  var current_li = $(this).parent();
  $(".accordion li div").each(function(i,el) {   
    if($(el).parent().is(current_li)) {    
      if ($(el).is(":visible")) {
        $(el).prev().toggleClass("plus fa-minus").toggleClass("fa-plus");
        $(el).slideUp().removeClass("plus");
      } else {
         $(el).prev().toggleClass("plus fa-minus").toggleClass("fa-plus");
         $(el).slideDown().addClass("plus")
      }
    } else{
      $(el).prev().removeClass("plus fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
      $(el).slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.accordion {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.accordion ul {
  border-bottom: #ecebe9 solid 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.accordion ul li {
  border-left: #ecebe9 solid 1px;
  border-right: #ecebe9 solid 1px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion ul li h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #f7f6f5;
  border-top: #ecebe9 solid 1px;
  border-left: #ecebe9 solid 0px;
  border-right: #ecebe9 solid 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 15px 12px 50px;
  line-height: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  
}

.accordion ul li h5.plus {
  border-bottom: #orange solid 1px;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion ul li > div {
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
}

.accordion ul li > div a {
  color: #7f0a19;
}

.accordion ul li h5.icon:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  background: #777;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
  top: 14px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.accordion ul li h5.plus:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Custom jQuery Accordion</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  <div class="accordion">
  <h2>Custom jQuery Accordion</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h5 class="icon plus fa-minus">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Lorem</h5>
      <div class="plus">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h5 class="icon fa-plus">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing dummy </h5>
      <div style="display: none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h5 class="icon fa-plus">Title Lorem Ipsum is dummy text of the printing</h5>
      <div style="display: none;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATED**

@Chris Happy, thanks for pointing out the error in the solution. I've corrected the errors in the CSS display property, as well as the class toggling on the accordion items.

Comment: Good catch @ChrisHappy. I've corrected my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you need to:

- Toggle the `.fa-plus` class when an item is clicked
- Remove `.fa-plus` class at the beginning.

JS Code:

```
$(".accordion li h5").click(function () {
  var current_li = $(this).parent();
  $(".accordion li div").each(function(i,el) {          
    if($(el).parent().is(current_li)) {             
      $(el).prev().toggleClass("fa-plus plus fa-minus"); // Toggle `fa-plus` as well
      $(el).slideToggle();              
    } else{
      $(el).prev().removeClass("plus fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
      $(el).slideUp();
    }
  });
});

$('.accordion li > div').hide();
$('.accordion li h5').first().addClass("plus fa-minus").removeClass("fa-plus"); // Remove `fa-plus`
$('.accordion li > div').first().show().addClass("plus");
```

Snippet:

```js
$(".accordion li h5").click(function () {
  var current_li = $(this).parent();
  $(".accordion li div").each(function(i,el) {   
    if($(el).parent().is(current_li)) {    
      $(el).prev().toggleClass("fa-plus plus fa-minus");
      $(el).slideToggle();    
    } else{
      $(el).prev().removeClass("plus fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
      $(el).slideUp();
    }
  });
});

$('.accordion li > div').hide();
$('.accordion li h5').first().addClass("plus fa-minus").removeClass("fa-plus");
$('.accordion li > div').first().show().addClass("plus");
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.accordion {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.accordion ul {
  border-bottom: #ecebe9 solid 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.accordion ul li {
  border-left: #ecebe9 solid 1px;
  border-right: #ecebe9 solid 1px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion ul li h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #f7f6f5;
  border-top: #ecebe9 solid 1px;
  border-left: #ecebe9 solid 0px;
  border-right: #ecebe9 solid 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 15px 12px 50px;
  line-height: 19px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  
}

.accordion ul li h5.plus {
  border-bottom: #orange solid 1px;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion ul li > div {
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
}

.accordion ul li > div a {
  color: #7f0a19;
}

.accordion ul li h5.icon:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  background: #777;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
  top: 14px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.accordion ul li h5.plus:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Custom jQuery Accordion</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>

  <div class="accordion">
  <h2>Custom jQuery Accordion</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h5 class="icon fa-plus">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Lorem</h5>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h5 class="icon fa-plus">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing dummy </h5>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h5 class="icon fa-plus">Title Lorem Ipsum is dummy text of the printing</h5>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/9qyuLtbm/)

Lastly, I'd recommend you caching `$(el)` or use the `$this`: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/9qyuLtbm/3/);

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I entirely understand your question, but perhaps this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/9p3mx52k/

```
$(".accordion li h5").click(function () {
  var current_li = $(this).parent();
  $(".accordion li").each(function(i,el) {          
    if($(el).is(current_li)) {
      if (current_li.find('> h5').hasClass('plus')) {
        $(el).find('> h5').removeClass("plus fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        $(el).find('> div').removeClass('plus').slideUp();
      } else {
        $(el).find('> h5').removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("plus fa-minus");
        $(el).find('> div').addClass('plus').slideDown();
      }
    } else{
      $(el).find('> h5').removeClass("plus fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
      $(el).find('> div').removeClass('plus').slideUp();
    }
  });
});
$('.accordion li > div').hide();
$('.accordion li h5').first().removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("plus fa-minus");
$('.accordion li > div').first().show().addClass("plus");
```

1. You didn't target all the correct elements.
2. The behavior is different depending on the state (open/closed, see `hasClass`) on the clicked element, so you cannot simply use the toggle functions.